# Swift 4 func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) not updating Int variable with indexPath.row

Tags: arrays, swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

all! I'm trying to combine previous lessons with the Audio Player, but I'm running into an issue. I have a variable `activeSong` which is equal to `indexPath.row` using the method `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. What happens is that when I print  `indexPath.row` its value is different form activeSong. Any idea why this might be happening. I think I'm doing something wrong with the func `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method. Thanks!!

```
/
//  MySongsController.swift
//  Audio Player
//
//  Created by Alex Gomez on 10/31/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Alex Gomez. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

var activeSong = -1
var isPlaying = false

class MySongsController: UITableViewController {

    var songsList = [Song()]

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if songsList.count == 1 && songsList[0].songTitle == "" {
            songsList.remove(at: 0)
            songsList.append(Song(songTitle: "El Colibri", songArtist: "Santiago Feliu", songFormat: "MP3"))
        }

        songsList.append(Song(songTitle: "Amargas Verdades", songArtist: "Santiago Feliu", songFormat: "MP3"))
        table.reloadData()

        // print("There are \(songsList.count) songs in the list")
        // print("Active song is \(activeSong)")
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // Number of cells
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return songsList.count
    }

    // Cell title
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(songsList[indexPath.row].songTitle) — \(songsList[indexPath.row].songArtist)"

        return cell
    }

    // Go to "Now Playing" view once a cell is selected
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toNowPlaying", sender: indexPath)
        activeSong = indexPath.row

        // print("—––––")
        // print("Index Path row is \(indexPath.row)")
        // print("Active song \(activeSong) — \(songsList[activeSong].songTitle)")

    }

    // Pass song information along to Now Playing view
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "toNowPlaying" {
            let nowPlayingView = segue.destination as! ViewController
            nowPlayingView.playing = activeSong
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the `activeSong` before you you call `performSegue(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `performSegue` before setting `activeSong`. Exchange the order.

Actually you don't need `activeSong`. As you hand over the `indexPath` anyway just use it:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toNowPlaying" {
        let nowPlayingView = segue.destination as! ViewController
        let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath
        nowPlayingView.playing = indexPath.row
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked. I guess I was missing the `let indexPath = sender as! IndexPath` line. Do you mind explaining me why `activeSong` was getting its initial value instead of `indexPath.row`? I'm sorry, I'm new to coding. Many thanks again!

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Change `performSegue(withIdentifier: "toNowPlaying", sender: indexPath)`

to `performSegue(withIdentifier: "toNowPlaying", sender: self)`