# swift tableview sentence bug

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to make a tableview where the user can click on the cells so the cells open a new ViewController which sets the navbar title to the clicked cell's label.
It doesn't really work for me because when I click on a cell it opens a view which has the previously clicked cell's value (not the current cells value) and then again opens a new view where the title is the current cells's value.
I uploaded the viewcontrollers to a GitHub repo: https://github.com/SiposPtr/stackoverflow

```
var selectedValue: String?
var numberOfFileToLoad: Int = 1
let cellak = [
    "Első",
    "Második",
    "Harmadik",
    "Negyedik",
    "Ötödik",
    "Hatodik",
    "Hetedik",
    "Nyolcadik",
    "Kilencedik"
]
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return cellak.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = cellak[indexPath.row]
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedValue = cellak[indexPath.row]
    numberOfFileToLoad = indexPath.row + 1
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoSentences", sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gotoSentences"{
        let nextViewController = segue.destination as! ButtonEditViewController
        nextViewController.title = selectedValue
        nextViewController.numberOfFileToLoad = numberOfFileToLoad
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Show storyboard screenshot

Comment: Please include relevant code, as text, in your question. Clearly explain what code is causing your issue.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/M9Cu8uc @RajeshKumarR here it is

Comment: @rmaddy that would be my whole tableviewcontroller file:)

Comment: Not if you only post code relevant to your issue.

Comment: And also if I'm not mistaken I uploaded both view controllers to GitHub so everyone can see it, so it's better than copy-pasting the whole project into my question

Comment: When seeking debugging help, it is inappropriate to simply post a link to an entire project and ask "where's my problem?". You are required to do your own debugging first and narrow down the issue to specific code. Then when asking your question, show just that relevant code. That's how this site works.

Comment: I totally agree and I'm sorry for being a moron

Comment: Instead of setting instance properties and then pushing to a detail view controller that's injected by those instance properties, IMO it's better practice to let the segue API pass the `indexPath` for you as shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53105072/swift-4-func-preparefor-segue-uistoryboardsegue-sender-any-not-updating-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `segue` is performed twice. If you have a `segue` connection from a table view cell to next view controller, the `segue` performed immediately after the cell is selected and `didSelectRowAt` method will be called after that.

You can get the selected row in `prepare for segue` method and pass the selected data to next view controller.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gotoSentences"{
        if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? ButtonEditViewController,
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                nextViewController.title = cellak[indexPath.row]
                nextViewController.numberOfFileToLoad = indexPath.row + 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It says "'UIViewController' is not convertible to 'ButtonEditViewController'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?" but when I replace 'as' with 'as!' it says: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'ButtonEditViewController'

Comment: @SiposPéter I've fixed it in my answer. You should use `as?`

Comment: @SiposPéter In `TableViewController` you don't need to have 2 instance properties `numberOfFileToLoad` and `selectedValue`. Unless you need to access these values in any other methods

Comment: I agree with @RajeshKumarR as you learn Swift, always default to the most limited scope possible (and that includes labeling properties and methods with access controls like `private`). And when a property or method needs a wider scope, grant it.